# BitmapEncoder MemoryLeak with SoftwareBitmap

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I use the [`BitmapEncoder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapencoder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class for converting a captured videoframe of a camera to a Stream. When doing this in a loop using a DispatcherTimer my application gradually leaks memory but never recovers any of it.

I used [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraGetPreviewFrame/cs) Microsoft sample as base.

The actual code that leaks.

```
var previewProperties = _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.GetMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview) as VideoEncodingProperties;
using (var videoFrame = new VideoFrame(BitmapPixelFormat.Rgba16, (int)previewProperties.Width, (int)previewProperties.Height))
{
    using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
    {
        using (var currentFrame = await _mediaCapture.GetPreviewFrameAsync(videoFrame))
        {
            // Collect the resulting frame
            using (SoftwareBitmap previewFrame = currentFrame.SoftwareBitmap)
            {

                BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, stream);
                //MEMORY LEAK
                encoder.SetSoftwareBitmap(previewFrame);
                await encoder.FlushAsync();

                //DO something with the stream
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to prevent the Memoryleak of course

Comment: @Freggar: You don't have a proof that there is a memory leak. At least try to force GC.Collect manually and waitForFinalization to see if there is any memory release. Keep in mind that .net apps trigger garbage collector and release memory only if there is a memory pressure.

Comment: Do not guess, get a memory profiler, and look what objects are not released, and by which objects are they held in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching harder and browsing through the MSDN forums I found a [MSDN thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c82cdf4a-fbb0-4e61-91ff-6a479a35f535/uwp-bitmapencodersetpixeldata-memory-leak?forum=wpdevelop/robots.txt) with exact the same issue. It's a bug in Visual Studio and does only affect apps while debugging them.